# Bidirectional many-to-many attribute_mapped_collection, sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have 2 classes as a many to many relationship A and B, shortened to show the basic relationship here:

```
class A(Base):

    bclss = relationship("B",
                          backref = "aclss",
                          secondary = "a_b_association",
                          collection_class = attribute_mapped_collection('identifier'))   

    a_b_association_table = Table('a_b_association', Base.metadata,
                             Column('a_id', Integer, ForeignKey('a.id')),
                             Column('b_id', Integer, ForeignKey('b.id')) )
```

So instances of A can add instances of B, and be referenced in a dictionary keyed by identifier...however B instances only contain a [list] of their a objects, and I would like a mirrored interface, to pull out a instances related to b instances by an identifier key in a dictionary. Mirroring the relationship statement on b and referencing the same association table does not work, so I'm thinking into an area I don't exactly know how to implement in sqlalchemy yet.

So, even if this isn't 100% clear, my question is this:

How to get a dictionary, attribute mapped collection on two items related in many to many relationship where each side can pull by dictionary key the related items instead of what I am getting: an asymetrical one side dictionary/other side list interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for (you just need to define a `backref` relationship in the many-to-many relationship with another `attribute_mapped_collection`):

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Table, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import attribute_mapped_collection


Base = declarative_base()


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


a_b_association_table = Table(
    'a_b_association', Base.metadata,
    Column('a_id', Integer, ForeignKey('a.id')),
    Column('b_id', Integer, ForeignKey('b.id'))
)


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    a_instances = relationship(
        A,
        backref = backref(
            'b_instances',
            collection_class = attribute_mapped_collection('id'),
        ),
        secondary = a_b_association_table,
        collection_class = attribute_mapped_collection('id'),
    )


engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
Base.metadata.bind = engine
Base.metadata.create_all()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = Session()

a1, a2, a3 = A(id=1), A(id=2), A(id=3)
b1, b2, b3 = B(id='a'), B(id='b'), B(id='c')

session.add_all([a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3])
session.flush()

print(a1.b_instances)
print(b1.a_instances)
a1.b_instances[b1.id] = b1
a1.b_instances[b2.id] = b2
b1.a_instances[a1.id] = a1
b1.a_instances[a2.id] = a2
session.flush()
session.expunge_all()
a1 = session.query(A).get(1)
b1 = session.query(B).get('a')
print(a1.b_instances)
print(b1.a_instances)
```

Output:

```
{}
{}
{u'a': <__main__.B object at 0x2816490>, u'b': <__main__.B object at 0x28b0350>}
{1: <__main__.A object at 0x28ac9d0>, 2: <__main__.A object at 0x28b0650>}
```

Comment: This is basically what I did first, and then went back after this and gave differing names instead of mirroring the names. You need two pairs of references one set for each class, not the same pair of references reversed on each class. The latter is where I got my error.